# Embed app.config in the application

Tags: .net, configuration

I have app.config with specified privatePath attribute of the probing element, to load assemblies from custom directory.

```
<configuration>
<runtime>
<assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
  <probing privatePath="Languages"/>
</assemblyBinding>
</runtime>
</configuration>
```

And this can work only if application config file is going with my application.
I also tried to make app.config as embeded resource, but that doesn't working..

Is there some way to make this without the application.exe.config file needed?

Thanks

Comment: what is the problem of having it separated as it is now? It's supposed to be available and editable without rebuilding the application, VS always copies it into the output directory on building the executable.

Comment: It's problem because users can delete it, edit it, corrupt it..etc.
And then loading assemblies wont work.

Comment: Anyone who has security rights to delete, edit or corrupt the config file can also delete, edit or corrupt the executable itself. There is nothing you can do to prevent this. If the empowered user chooses to tinker with the installed application then it is their own responsibility, rather than yours, to make sure they do not break it.

Comment: I understand that. So there is no easy way to embed the file?